# ANTLR match declaration only

Tags: java, antlr, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to write a parser with ANTLR4 that should parse a very simple model file from [hyperledger](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language.html):

```
asset Car identified by id {
  o String id
  o String model
  --> Owner owner
}

participant Owner identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
}

transaction Auction {
  --> Car asset
  o String newValue
}
```

I'm having a problem within the transaction: I can't give the variable of type Car the name 'asset', which is valid in the language specification. The ANTLR parser doesn't expect that. I get an exception similar like that: `mismatched input 'o' expecting {'[', IDENTIFIER}` I know the cause is the assetDeclaration in my grammar, which detects the asset keyword in the transaction as well.

Is there a way to ignore the asset within the transaction? Or can I make the declaration more specific, so that it is triggered when the asset is at the start and followed by letters?

This is my asset declaration:

```
assetDeclaration: ASSET IDENTIFIER
  (EXTENDS typeType)?
  IDENTIFIED
  IDENTIFIER
  classBody;
```

And my transaction declaration:

```
transactionDeclaration: TRANSACTION IDENTIFIER
  classBody
;
```

Asset, Transaction and so on defined as:

```
 ASSET: 'asset';
 TRANSACTION: 'transaction';
 IDENTIFIED: 'identified by';
 PARTICIPANT: 'participant';
```

The rest of the grammar is similar to the JavaGrammar which is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java)

Comment: The name for this is "non-reserved keyword" - a word that has some special meaning to the language, but may also be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

If `asset` is allowed to appear anywhere where an identifier is allowed, you can just define `identifier: IDENTIFIER | ASSET;` and then use `identifier` everywhere instead of `IDENTIFIER`.

If `asset` is only allowed in certain places where identifiers are allowed, you should explicitly write `(IDENTIFIER | ASSET)` in those places.

The same applies to any other keywords that are also legal as identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me.